# ng-model not updating with on-screen keyboard on Chrome OS

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-os

A ChromeOS device puts up a virtual keyboard when you select in an input.

Inside my angular component I have an `input` control bound to a property:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.searchText" />
```

I want this to work via a touch screen.
If I click in the control, the touch screen keyboard appears.

I press the touch keys and the letters appear in the input, but the `set searchText` method doesn't get called until the text box loses focus.

If I plug in a USB keyboard and enter text, the `set searchText` method gets called with every new character. It just fails with the onscreen touch keyboard.

I tried setting different options using [ngModelOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions):

```
<input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.searchText" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'keyup keydown default blur click touch touchup touchdown'}" />
```

This does not change the behavior.

---

I've created the simplest example I could using Plunker. Sure enough, if I browse to the site on the chrome device and use the touch keyboard, the value does not update as you add text. But if I use a USB keyboard, it does update.

http://embed.plnkr.co/bIwMp88BB8gNHFenayfz/

---

I found [this Keyboard Event Viewer utility](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/tools/key-event-viewer.html) which prints out the exact sequence of keyboard-related events.

I notice some things that are different about the chrome onscreen keyboard:

- the `keyup` event fires with the `key` value sets to unidentified.
- the onscreen keyboard fires extra events: `compositionstart`, `compositionupdate`, but seems to be flakey around the `compositionend` event.

When I enter the 'a' key via the keyboard, the following events are fired:

```
| Event type        | data | Input Field |
|-------------------|------|-------------|
| keydown           |      | ''          |
| keypress          |      | ''          |
| beforeinput       | 'a'  | ''          |
| input             | 'a'  | 'a'         |
| keyup             |      | 'a'         |
```

When I enter the 'a' key using the touch screen, the following events are fired. These are the same events, but with the added `compositionstart`, `compositionupdate` events.

```
| Event type        | data | Input Field |
|-------------------|------|-------------|
| keydown           |      | ''          |
| compositionstart  |      | ''          |
| beforeinput       | 'a'  | ''          |
| compositionupdate | 'a'  | ''          |
| input             | 'a'  | 'a'         |
| keyup             |      | 'a'         |
```

It needs to fire the `compositionend` event. But it doesn't!

The `composition` events are very significant in the angular code. The [relevant code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/c484213180470c2a8044eeb09dfdc5ef11099bc8/src/ng/directive/input.js#L1247) is in input.js, where it defers any handling until the `compositionend` event:

```
   // In composition mode, users are still inputting intermediate text buffer,
  // hold the listener until composition is done.
  // More about composition events: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CompositionEvent
  if (!$sniffer.android) {
    var composing = false;

    element.on('compositionstart', function() {
      composing = true;
    });

    // Support: IE9+
    element.on('compositionupdate', function(ev) {
      // End composition when ev.data is empty string on 'compositionupdate' event.
      // When the input de-focusses (e.g. by clicking away), IE triggers 'compositionupdate'
      // instead of 'compositionend'.
      if (isUndefined(ev.data) || ev.data === '') {
        composing = false;
      }
    });

    element.on('compositionend', function() {
      composing = false;
      listener();
    });
  }

  //....

  var listener = function(ev) {
     // ...
     if (composing) return;
     // ...
  }
```

---

I have submitted this as a defect to google:

[Entering character with on-screen keyboard fails to trigger 'compositionend' event](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=818881)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick answer: add the attribute `autocorrect='off'` to the input element.

---

I posted a video of my experience to the chrome bug tracking forums.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=818881

Here is the response from the chrome development team:

> This is by design. Same behavior on Android with Android keyboard apps.
>   The composition text in the case in the video recording is "a" with the underline effect. "compositionend" event will appear after the underlined text is committed by, e.g. SPACE key.
>
> In your application, if you don't want IME/VK to set composition text in your input field, please set the attribute "autocorrect=false" [sic] to the input element or content editable element.